# Two Firebase Cloud Messages on a single android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently working on an Android App and I'm using FCM service in it.
I have already successfully sent a Firebase Cloud Message on it but now what I have to do now is, send two different FCM on the same app. 
Please help me to achieve it..

Comment: If you want to create a new message for the same app then it is as simple as creating another notification for the new message

Comment: @raxerz what about "Notification Channel ID"?
should it be same for both messages?

Comment: @UgurcanYildirim that's a complete different thing.

Comment: I believe the notification id is just to identify the app and is not related to having different messages

Comment: okay, thanks! @raxerz